# Lightning Web Component Rendering Issues

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, html, lightning-record-page

I have recently been working on embedding power bi into a salesforce LWC, as outlined here: https://github.com/PowerBiDevCamp/SalesforceAppOwnsDataEmbedding. Pretty cool stuff, but the particular use case may be beside the point. I am having some sort of rendering issues with the lightning web component. Here it is:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getEmbeddingDataForReport from '@salesforce/apex/PowerBiEmbedManager.getEmbeddingDataForReport';
import powerbijs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/powerbijs';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class PowerBiReport extends LightningElement {
  @api WorkspaceId = '';
  @api ReportId = '';
  @api recordId;
   
  @wire(getEmbeddingDataForReport,{
    WorkspaceId: "$WorkspaceId",
    ReportId: "$ReportId"
  }) report;
    renderedCallback() {
      Promise.all([ loadScript(this, powerbijs ) ]).then(() => {
        if(this.report.data){
              if(this.report.data.embedUrl && this.report.data.embedToken){
                const reportContainer = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="embed-container"');
                const reportId = this.report.data.reportId;

                const embedUrl = this.report.data.embedUrl;
                const token = this.report.data.embedToken;

                var visualConfig = {
                  accessToken: token,
                  embedUrl: embedUrl,
                  id: reportId,
                  pageName: 'ReportSection',
                  tokenType: 1,
                  type: 'visual',
                  visualName: '1837fab00804802016c6',
                  settings: {
                    panes: {
                      filters: { expanded: false, visible: true },
                      pageNavigation: { visible: false}
                    }
                  }
                }
                // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
                var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, visualConfig); 
              }
              else {
                console.log('no embedUrl or embedToken');
              }
                
              }
              else{
                  console.log('no report.data yet');
              }
        });
    }
}
```

Now this works fine and as intended. The getEmbeddingDataForReport returns all the necessary data (embed url, token, etc...), and I have the chart embedding and showing up (mostly) properly. I have the lightning web component on a lightning record page. But here's the problem. Occasionally when the page loads, I get an error message: [image]

After occasionally getting this error pop-up, I did some digging and noticed that I ALWAYS get it if I click on 'Edit Page' to pull up the lightning page where the LWC is embedded. When opening the console, I see this error message duplicated about 4 or 5 times: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': # could not be cloned." [image]

After logging at some random places, I noticed that I do not get this error if I comment out the line where powerbi.embed uses the configurations and selected html id to embed the actual report. So, there is either something wrong with this line:

```
var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, visualConfig);
```

or this line:

```
const reportContainer = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="embed-container"');
```

I am pretty stumped on this. I don't have the slightest idea why this could be happening. I read a couple things online that indicated this error often relates to embedding a LWC in a context that doesn't support LWCs and that the solution would be to wrap the LWC in an Aura component; however, I don't believe that applies here because the LWC is embedded in a lightning record page, which clearly supports LWCs. So, somethings is going on under the hood here relating to one of those two lines I pointed out...any ideas what is happening here? Please help!!

Comment: How many times is the renderedCallback function being called?

Comment: Nick is correct, you need a boolean lock to prevent multiple loads. Check out how we did it here with another lib: https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsFullCalendar/libsFullCalendar.js#L19

Comment: I tried this, but this does not appear to be the problem. renderedCallback is only being called twice, once when the LWC initially renders and once when it gets the power bi data. This is expected. There is some sort of issue with the .embed() method.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely getting this error because there is an issue with the `powerbi.js` that you uploaded as a Static Resource. I had this issue on v2.21.1 of `powerbi.js`.

This issue can be tracked down to the function assigned to `WindowPostMessageProxy.prototype.sendResponse`. I deep cloned `message` [as per this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42376465/6899015) and it seemed to do the trick. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223341) explains the reasoning behind the error very well.

The `message` parameter being passed to this function can also occasionally be null, so I added a null check and for `message` and all was good to go.

After my fix, the function looks something like this:

```
WindowPostMessageProxy.prototype.sendResponse = function (targetWindow, message, trackingProperties) {
    this.addTrackingProperties(message, trackingProperties);
    if (this.logMessages) {
        console.log(this.name + " Sending response:");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(message, null, '  '));
    }
    if (!message) {
        return;
    }
    message = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(message))
    targetWindow.postMessage(message, "*");
};
```

As an aside, I believe the `powerbi.js` is now at v2.22.2 based on the link in the PowerBiDevCamp repo, so that might also fix your issue. If it does not, I can vouch for the stability of v2.21.1 after applying the above fix.